# XML Schema - constraint on variable in list

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a schema where I want a particular constraint on a list. In the `Employees` element under `Firm`, I need all the `DepartmentId`'s in the list of employees to be the same. So if an instance of `Firm` have the `DepartmentId` of `1378`, the `Firm` object is only valid if all the `Employees` have that same ID. Is this possible to do with XSD? It would be best if this can be put here, so I don't need to check for this after validating the object against the XSD in the code.

```
<element name="Firm">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="Name" type="string" />
            <element name="Employees" type="tns:Employee" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>

<complexType name="Employee">
    <sequence>
        <element name="EmployeeId" type="string" />
        <element name="DepartmentId" type="string" />
        <element name="Department" type="string" />
        <element name="Name" type="string" />
        <element name="Description" type="string" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

Your constraint *cannot* be expressed in XSD 1.0.

### XSD 1.1

Your constraint *can* be expressed in XSD 1.1 via `xs:assert`:

```
<xs:assert test="count(distinct-values(tns:Employees/tns:DepartmentId)) = 1"/>
```

**In context...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://example.com/tns"
    targetNamespace="http://example.com/tns"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:element name="Firm">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Employees" type="tns:Employee"
                            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:assert test="count(distinct-values(tns:Employees/tns:DepartmentId))
                             = 1"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Employee">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="EmployeeId" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="DepartmentId" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Department" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Then this XML will be *valid*:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Firm>
    <Name></Name>
    <Employees>
        <EmployeeId></EmployeeId>
        <DepartmentId>1378</DepartmentId>
        <Department></Department>
        <Name></Name>
        <Description></Description>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <EmployeeId></EmployeeId>
        <DepartmentId>1378</DepartmentId>
        <Department></Department>
        <Name></Name>
        <Description></Description>
    </Employees>
</Firm>
```

**But this XML will be *invalid*:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Firm>
    <Name></Name>
    <Employees>
        <EmployeeId></EmployeeId>
        <DepartmentId>1378</DepartmentId>
        <Department></Department>
        <Name></Name>
        <Description></Description>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <EmployeeId></EmployeeId>
        <DepartmentId>9999</DepartmentId>
        <Department></Department>
        <Name></Name>
        <Description></Description>
    </Employees>
</Firm>
```

**as requested.**

Comment: That's great! I actually chose a bit of a bad example, since the id can be both numbers or text and numbers (1378 or A-1101 for example). Is it still possible to do this in some way if there's both letters and numbers?

Comment: `DepartmentId` can contain letters; it'll still work.